# `types` option in TSConfig doesn't work as stated in the TS docs

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig, tsconfig.json

I think TSConfig `types` option doesn't work as [stated in the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types).

I installed npm packages, `express`, `@types/express`, `node`, `@types/node`, `lodash`, `@types/lodash` and `moment`.
And i wrote TSConfig like below.

```json
{
  "include": ["./main.ts", "./src"],
  "exclude": ["./src/**/DummyComp.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "ES5",
    "types": ["node", "express"]
  }
}
```

As mentioned in TS docs, only `type definition files` of `node` and `express` should be included and will have exports appear as auto-import recommendations.

But auto-import recommendation of `moment` and `lodash` (omitted in `type` option) appear like below image.

[image]

[image]

How is this possible?

As stated in TS docs, `lodash` and `moment`'s auto-import recommendations don't appear.

Comment: What is the exact issue? Not sure I follow.

Comment: The issue is that omitted package in `type` options, should not appear auto import suggestion. but it appear like above images.
I don't know the reason, because TSDocs says that `omitted package will not have exports appear as auto-import recommendations`.
Did i misunderstand?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I use vscode @RobinThomas

Comment: Whats  your typescript version?

Comment: My ts version is 5.1.6 @RobinThomas

Answer (score 0):

The only way to exclude from VS Code auto-import suggestions (files that need to be included) is to use:

```
{
    // Note that `javascript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns` can be specified for JavaScript too.
    "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
      "**/node_modules/@types/node"
    ]
}
```

> TypeScript 4.8 introduces an editor preference for excluding files from auto-imports. In Visual Studio Code, file names or globs can be added under "Auto Import File Exclude Patterns" in the Settings UI, or in a .vscode/settings.json file:
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#exclude-specific-files-from-auto-imports

---

If the files don't have to compiled, you can use the `exclude` property in `tsconfig.json`.